# Custom Shortcut For "Grouped window list"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am currently using -
Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa (Cinnamon 4.0.10)

I am using **Grouped window list** by default.

When a group of windows is open and I right click, it has options for **close all** and **close others**.

[image: screenshot of right click menu]

I need to assign shortcut for these two commands. How can I do that?

Comment: How would the shortcut know which group of windows to close though? I mean, you are describing a GUI feature, so how would the keyboard shortcut know which of the various groups of windows you have open should be closed? Will it always be the windows you have in focus currently?